# sound not playing in UILocal notification

Tags: ios, iphone

Hello i set the name of sound to UILocal notification but its not playing  it correct but sound is not ringing when notification is fired as well as default sound also not playing.
song formate is .waw which is supported by apple..

**Source code:**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];  
UILocalNotification *notification=[[UILocalNotification alloc]init];  
notification.fireDate=[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:100];  
notification.alertBody=@"Time to wake up";  
notification.alertAction = @"Snooze";  
notification.soundName=@"Guitar.wav";  
//notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;  
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution of my problem that is in iphone's notification center my app sound is off, so i just turn on it and its working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this two way and get which is for you ?

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5];

    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"You have long time to care your......";
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber]+1;
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotification.repeatInterval = kCFCalendarUnitMinute;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
    [localNotification release];
    localNotification = nil;
```

////////////OR///////////////

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];

   // Set the notification time.
    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];

   // You can specify the alarm sound here.
   localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
   //OR
   localNotification.soundName = @"sound.caf";

   // Set the alertbody of the notification here.
    localNotification.alertBody = @"Test Alert";

   // Create the buttons on the notification alertview.
    localNotification.alertAction = @"View";

   // You can also specify custom dictionary to store informations
    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"alarm#2" forKey:@"notifiKey"];
    localNotification.userInfo = infoDict;

    //Repeat the notification.
    localNotification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;

// Schedule the notification
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your sound to caf format int terminal with command:

```
afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@44100 -c 1 in.wav out.caf
```

And make sure the sound is under 30 sec.